# How to start()/stop() ear application programmatically in IBM WAS?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, websphere, jboss-arquillian

I am going to test my ear application on IBM WAS 8.5.5 using Arquillian framework. I managed to deploy, start and send a JMS message to my ear apllication and ear had processed this message as planned. According our business logic each ear implements IBM autostart behaviour for one of its inner EJB components (say it is a Stateless Session Bean) so component`s ejb-jar.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>MyBusinessEjb</ejb-name>
            <home>com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUpHome</home>
            <remote>com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUp</remote>
        </session>
        ...
```

and the code of some inner EJB is:

```
@Stateless(name = "MyBusinessEjb")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyBusinessEjbBean implements TimedObject {

    public boolean start() {
        ... init some resources here
        return true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        ... free resources here
    }

    ...
```

But alas - Arquillian does not let application to call the start() and stop() methods. They automatically called (not using annotated or deployment-descriptor-specified interceptors, just called by IBM WAS) when administrator runs an application from IBM Console.
In my test EJB (it is loading by arquillian when my ear application has already deployed) I can make a lookup for MyBusinessEjb:

```
public void tryToCallStart() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    Object beanObj = ic.lookup("java:global/ear-app-1.0.0/ejb-module/MyBusinessEjb");
    AppStartUpHome beanHome = (AppStartUpHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(beanObj, AppStartUpHome.class);
```

but JNDI returns only AppStartUpHome stub, not AppStartUp on which I could call startup(), and the following:

```
beanHome.create().start();
```

ofcourse just creates and starts another bean instance, not mine :(

So how can I call start() method on MyBusinessEjb inside my ear-app-1.0.0 before or during Arquillian test running? Or maybe some one has any other idea how start() could be called - using arquillian.xml or Maven pom.xml where my tests are executed?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know if to programatically start or stop applications in WebSphere is using AdminControl from the wsadmin command line interface.  You could write some code to execute a wsadmin script that would perform the start/stop for you.

Perhaps something like this: (disclaimer, untested)

```
// any ${var} pieces are variables you will have to fill in
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/wsadmin.sh/bat", 
  "-conntype SOAP}",  
  "-host ${HOST}",
  "-port ${SOAP_PORT}",
  "-user ${USER_ID}",
  "-password ${PASS}",
  "-c $AdminControl invoke " + 
     "[$AdminControl queryNames cell=${CELL},node=${NODE},type=ApplicationManager,process=${PROCESS},*]" + 
     " startApplication ${APPLICATION_NAME}");
Process p = pb.start();
```